# How to use curiefense configuration management tool?

Tags: config, configuration-management

I want to explore curiefense to check out if we can update, modify, edit the contents of a configuration file or not. But i am unable to understand how to do so.

There are a lot of option on the dashboard, but where will the changes be reflected. I want to know how to use it.